# Moment.js Days Missing from Duration

Tags: diff, momentjs, duration

I'm using moment.js to create a duration from the difference between two dates.

```
var now         = moment();
var future      = moment("2017-4-17 23:18:30");
var diff        = future.diff(now);
var duration    = moment.duration(diff);
```

For some reason, the duration is two days longer than it should be. The years, months, hours, minutes, and seconds all seem accurate... What's going on?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem, anyway I suggest to use `moment("2017-4-17 23:18:30", "YYYY-M-D HH:mm:ss")` instead of `moment("2017-4-17 23:18:30")`, see [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: Now I see that results from `moment(now).add(duration._data)` and `moment(now).add(duration)` differ (in my case it's about 1,5 day) and `duration.days()` returns days stored in `duration._data`. Report it as bug. Functions as `duration.asDays`,`asHours` etc. rely on `duration._milliseconds` and give better results, but you have to format it on your own